# Do Keras epoch-counting callbacks work across several fitting sessions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Some Keras callbacks, like `ModelCheckpoint` or `ReduceLROnPlateau`, rely on counting the number of epochs that some condition is met until some action is taken.

For certain purposes I need to train a Keras model in several fitting sessions, so something like

```py
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
   model.fit(data, epochs=1)
```

rather than

```py
model.fit(data, epochs=num_epochs)
```

I was wondering if Keras callbacks work even if I use them across several fitting sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time `model.fit(...)` is called `callbacks.History` is reset. So no, it will not work like that. While you could log yourself as @kacpo1 mentioned and save each, you may benefit from the `train_on_batch(...)` method. This performs a single update and you can set `reset_metrics=False` in the method call to retain your metrics.

https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#trainonbatch-method

Answer (score 2):

```
I was wondering if Keras callbacks work even if I use them across several fitting sessions.
```

The answer is no. If you doing things this way (loop with fitting one epoch at time) you can do those things like saving weights and learning rate decay by yourself without using callbacks.

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.fit(data, epochs=1)
    if epoch % 5 == 0:
        model.save_weights(...)
```